# WebView en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion que usa el webview ella me carga la pagina web pero en el momento de descargar un video no me deja. Que es lo que tengo q hacer

Comment: Hola!, considera compartir el código de lo que haz intentado

Comment: Estaría bueno que añadas el código.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías probar esto:

**XML:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**WebView:**

```
mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                long contentLength) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

**O probar de esta manera:**

```
mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {       

    @Override
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                    long contentLength) {
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                    Uri.parse(url));

            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED); //Notificación que indica que la descarga está completa
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "El nombre del archivo va acá, por ejemplo: Matematicas II");
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Descargando Archivo", //Enviamos una notificación al Cliente por la descarga
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```